# Cluster laser stage lighting

Tags: effects, lighting

I'm not entirely sure if this is on-topic here, since it's about stage lighting rather than audio or video directly, but I'll give it a shot.

I've been looking at various types of laser stage lighting, and I'm trying to work out how they work internally. I figure the scanning lasers (single fast-moving beam) work by firing a single laser onto a rotating mirror, or a mirror controlled by servos for more precise movements.

However, I can't figure out how the cluster lasers work. I'd guess there's some kind of prism in there, or some trickery with a set of mirrors and lenses that somehow "split" the beam, but I can't quite figure it out. My first thought was a fixed prism, but that wouldn't explain how these devices can spread, focus and rotate the beams.

How do these laser effects usually work?

Comment: The question as to whether lighting questions are on topic or not [has been asked](http://meta.avp.stackexchange.com/questions/177/are-lighting-questions-on-topic), though I don't think it's been settled.  There are a number of questions tagged [lighting], though most of those have a production angle.  You're a little bit in uncharted territory here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way most stage laser effects work is by using a holographic plate or diffraction grating which splits the single beam up into multiple beams.

*[image removed due to a DMCA request from copyright holder]*

These then pass to further holographic elements to provide shapes and lines, and these can then be manipulated further with lenses or mirrors.

Comment: That's pretty cool. So it works a little bit like the [double-slit experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment)?

Comment: Very much so - when I did my laser optics course we actually used double slit slides, but apparently now holographic plates are all the rage, and can produce from 2 to millions of individual beams!

Comment: I'll have to look into holographic plates. Might warrant a post on physics.SE, actually.

Comment: Any idea what a good search term is for finding these plates? eBay produces some [undesirable results](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/150947939673) if you search for "holographic plate".

Comment: "holograph laser elements" seems to work okay

Comment: very cool indeed :)